# Adding raster to PostgreSQL database using raster2pgsql?

Tags: qgis, raster2pgsql

I added a raster to my PG database using the raster2pgsql and when I try to load it from QGIS it says that I need to specify it's geometry. Is that a common problem, and if so, how can I solve it?

The command that I used was

```
raster2pgsql -s 2100 -c C:\Users\user\Desktop\data\raster_2100.tif public.raster2 | psql -h localhost -U user1 -p
```

and SELECT * FROM raster_column prints this:

[image]

Comment: Did you import as an in- or out-of-database raster? Does it show as registered in the raster_columns catalog?

Comment: The raster that I am referring to was at my local disk, so I imported in to my database at first and then out of my database into my QGIS session. Now, about that raster_columns are you referring to my database? Because I have no column named like that.

Comment: What does it return if you run 'SELECT * FROM raster_columns' ?

Comment: @scabecks see my edit

Comment: From that you can tell it's not registering properly. Try re-importing the raster, adding the -C flag (-I to build an index too is a good idea often).

Comment: There is still the error and I don't know. Why is there still this error.

Comment: How big is your raster? Perhaps tiling it may help if it's large.

Comment: @scabecks Op, it's about 15 MB maybe that's what is causing the problem

Comment: Shouldn't be. That's not big at all. What version of postgis are you running?

Comment: the version is 2.2.0

Comment: @GeorgeNostradamos How are you adding the raster layer in QGIS? The standard Add PostGIS Layer functionality doesn't support raster types. Instead try the DB Manager plug-in - all being well, you should be able to just drag and drop your raster table onto the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

When I first attempted to upload the raster to my database I was convinced that `raster2psql` was the best way to do that, but I decided to find another way through R, mainly from the library `rpostgis`, now I haven't solved it using `raster2psql` but because I am working with R as well, I have to say that the command `pgWriteRast` does the same work.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have the raster in your filesystem you can create the sql file with

```
raster2pgsql <rasteroptions> <raster_file> <some_schema.sometable> > out.sql
E.g. raster2psql -s 4326 -I -C -M coast.tif -F -t 100x100 public.coast > coast.sql
```

You can see all the rasteroptions here: https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html

After you created the SQL-file you need to add the data to the database/table:
This is the syntax to connect to the database and enter the data by the SQL-file to the database.

```
psql -h localhost -d dbname - U user -f path/to/file.sql
```

At least this is how it works for me.

And if you are a Windows user you should  split this commend into two

> raster2pgsql -s 2100 -c C:\Users\user\Desktop\data\raster_2100.tif public.raster2 | psql -h localhost -U user1 -p